# Is the homology theory given by Eilenberg Maclane spectrum equal to ordinary homology?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homotopy-theory, eilenberg-maclane-spaces

(I think I'm missing something very simple). Let $R$ be a ring and $HR$ the associated Eilenberg-Maclane spectrum, defined by 
$$[\Sigma^\infty_+ X,HR]_{-*}={H}^*(X; R)$$
for any  CW-complex $X$, and where ${H}^*(X; R)$ denotes ordinary cohomology with $R$ coefficients.

My questions is, do we have the following equality and if so, why $$[S, HR \wedge \Sigma^\infty_+ X]_* = {H}_*(X; R) \ ?$$

The left hand side is what $HR_*(\Sigma X)$ is defined to be, so that is why I suspect it should equal the right hand side, i.e ordinary homology with $R$ coefficients, but I don't see how that follows.

Comment: Do you know the Cartan-Steenrod axioms for a homology theory?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez Oh, I see Eilenberg-Steenrod axioms are a quick way to see the equation is true. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

As Mariano suggested in the comment, the reason that the equation is true is because the functor $X \mapsto [S, HR \wedge \Sigma_+^\infty X]$ satisfies the Eilenberg-Steenrod axioms for homology, including the dimension axiom: if $X$ is a point, then $\Sigma^\infty_+ X=S$, the sphere spectrum, and hence the value of this functor is 
$$[S, HR \wedge S]_*=[S, HR]_*=\pi_*(HR) =\left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
R & *=0 \\
0 & \text{otherwise} 
\end{array}
\right.
$$